# Parallel computing with R in a SLURM cluster

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, slurm, doparallel

I need to do a model estimation using the MCMC method on a SLURM cluster (the system is `CentOS`). The estimation takes a very long time to finish.

Within each MCMC interaction, there is one step taking a particularly long time. Since this step is doing a lapply-loop (around 100000 loops, 30s to finish all loops), so as far as I understand, I should be able to use parallel computing to speed up.

I tried several packages (`doMC`, `doParallel`, `doSNOW`) together with the `foreach` framework. The setup is

```
  parallel_cores=8
  
  #doParallel
  library(doParallel) 
  cl<-makeCluster(parallel_cores)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  
  #doMC
  library(doMC)
  registerDoMC(parallel_cores)
  
  
  #doSNOW, this is also fast
  library(doSNOW)
  ml<-makeCluster( parallel_cores)
  registerDoSNOW(cl)


  #foreach framework
  #data is a list
  data2=foreach(
        data_i=
          data,
        .packages=c("somePackage")
      ) %dopar% {
        data_i=some_operation(data_i)
        
        list(beta=data_i$beta,sigma=data_i$sigma)

      }
```

Using a `doMC`, the time for this step can be reduced to about 9s. However, as `doMC` is using shared memory and I have a large array to store estimate results, I quickly ran out of memory (i.e. `slurmstepd: error: Exceeded job memory limit`).

Using `doParallel` and `doSNOW`, the time for this step even increased, to about 120s, which sounds ridiculous. The mysterious thing is that when I tested the code in both my Mac and Windows machines, `doParallel` and `doSNOW` actually gave similar speed compared to `doMC`.

I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it can be stored in a matrix, then you can use data on disk (shared memory) to store results with e.g. package {bigstatsr} (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Hi @F.Privé, the estimation result is stored in a 3-dimensional array. Can bigstatsr work on array?

Comment: No it can't, but you can always see a 3D array as a matrix.